# "java.sql.SQLException: No database selected" with MySQL JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Code:

```
Connection dbConnection;
public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://127.2.0.1:3306/?user=root?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false";
;
String url="?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);
    return dbConnection;

}
public void SingUpUser(String id,String login, String password) {
    String insert = "INSERT INTO"+Constant.USER_TABLE+"("+Constant.USERS_ID+","+Constant.USERS_LOGIN+","+Constant.USER_PASSWORD+")"+
"VALUES(?,?,?)";


    try {
        PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
        prSt.setString(1, id);
        prSt.setString(2, login);
        prSt.setString(3, password);
        prSt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:955)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1094)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1345)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1027)
at minelaunch.Databases.SingUpUser(Databases.java:36)
at minelaunch.minelauncherv1$5.actionPerformed(minelauncherv1.java:182)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I expect to write to the database, but I get this error.

Comment: Please post the full exception stack trace

Comment: i posted the full exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stack trace:

> java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

You have removed the database name from your connection string, so now MySQL does not know which database you want to work with. Edit your connection string again and  specify the actual name of the database you want to use.

Comment: i copy jdbc url from MySQL, but now another error, 
I'll edit the error, if you can, then look at it

Comment: thank, sheck please? this errorhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415526/errorcom-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-coul