# Error:java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'loginpass.intousers' doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am unable to establish a connection to my MySQL database.
if loginpass.users than database not

```
Connection dbConnection;
public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://127.2.0.1:3306/loginpass?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
;
    String url="?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);
    return dbConnection;

}
public void SingUpUser(String id,String login, String password) {
    String insert = "INSERT INTO"+Constant.USER_TABLE+"("+Constant.USERS_ID+","+Constant.USERS_LOGIN+","+Constant.USER_PASSWORD+")"+
"VALUES(?,?,?)";


    try {
        PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
        prSt.setString(1, id);
        prSt.setString(2, login);
        prSt.setString(3, password);
        prSt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

CONSOLE:

```
   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'loginpass.intousers' doesn't exist
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:955)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1094)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1345)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1027)
at minelaunch.Databases.SingUpUser(Databases.java:36)
at minelaunch.minelauncherv1$5.actionPerformed(minelauncherv1.java:182)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: _"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'loginpass.users'"_ you dont have a database called `loginpass.users`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Comment: You may have fixed the initial error that caused your connection problem, but likely the value of `Constant.USER_TABLE` (not shown in your question), is still wrong, not to mention that the lack of a space after `INSERT INTO` is suspect. Change your code to `"INSERT INTO " + Constant.USER_TABLE ...`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I just wanted to thank you from the bottom of my heart for you mentioning the space after the INTO. I spent 3 hours wondering where I went wrong, and I forgot the space. As soon as I read your comment I was saying, "There's no way I did that." and it turns out I did. but thank you for saving me so much time

Comment: @JohnnyRobertson You're welcome :)